# How can I expand external image links in all webpage with a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, images, links

So I would like to when the script find a image link like this:

```
http://example.com/image.gif
http://example.com/image.jpg
http://example.com/image.png
```

Replace with a img tag, for I can view the image directly in the actual site.
For example:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.gif">
```

Is that possible somehow?
More details:

1. I would like to use for this tampermonkey
2. The script find the http text on the page automatically,and turn in to link(provided that no link yet).
   If the link end png,jpg,jpeg,gif etc, the script turn this link to img.

I tried this way:

```
// ==UserScript==
    // @name         My Fancy New Userscript
    // @namespace    http://your.homepage/
    // @version      0.1
    // @description  enter something useful
    // @author       You
    // @match        http://*/*
    // @grant        none
    // @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
    // @require http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/addvideos/jquery.linkify.min.js
    // ==/UserScript==
    $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('p').linkify();
    $('span').linkify();
    $("a").attr("href", src);
    $('a').html(function(index,html){
    return html.replace(/<\img>(\:)/,'');
     });
    });
```

But unfortunetly I can't wirte the regex for the `<a>` tag.
And the second problem is :
The Same-origin policy, which not realy let me run script on the websites.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but it's not clearly defined what you need. Can you give a very concrete example? Are the links actual `<a>` anchors or just text? Do you want a userscript or… ? What have you tried already?

Comment: I expaneded my question, I hope now clear.

Comment: Yeah, but it would  be good to show what you already have. We don't really encourage questions which are basically script requests.

Comment: Okey, I aded what I tryed.